# Error when updating from PHP 5.4 to 7.4: "Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress."

Tags: php, wordpress

I recently updated my site hosted on HostGator from PHP 5.4 to 7.4. I got this error:

Warning: Use of undefined constant WP_CONTENT_DIR - assumed 'WP_CONTENT_DIR' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /home1/keziavida/public_html/wp-includes/load.php on line 115
Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.

Deprecated: Directive 'allow_url_include' is deprecated in Unknown on line 0

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: [the mysql extension is deprecated since php 5.5 and removed in 7.0](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql.installation.php) You need to install mysqli.